# jquery, checkbox updating div

Tags: jquery, append

I have the js to remove the checkbox selection on click of the `<a>` beside the items in testDiv, but was wondering how to remove the correspoding element from  testDiv when an element is unchecked, also is there a way can I add add title of an item instead of value, as I have junk characters in value attribute. Tried different ways but facing one or the other issue.

```
$(":input").live('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ($("<span/>", {
            class: 'bckeys',
            html: $this.val() + "<a class='rempills'>"
        })).appendTo('#testDiv');
    }
});


$('#testDiv').on('click', '.bckeys', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('label[title="' + $.trim($this.text()) + '"]').prev('input').prop('checked', false);

    $this.remove();
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/589qp/**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input").on('change', function () {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        $("<span/>", {
            'class': 'bckeys ' + this.id,
            html: "<a class='rempills'>" + $(this).next('label').prop('title') + "</a>"
        }).appendTo('#testDiv');
    }else{
        $('.'+this.id, '#testDiv').remove();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/589qp/2/)

Comment: This works for the element with in the checkbox group, but how to handle the onload items that gets added to the testDiv, unchecking the elements that are added on load would not be removed with the js above...is there a way to handle both these together?